# Unable to implement subtract function with consecutive inputs. Unable to find proper logic to implement in a calculator app

Tags: ios, objective-c

The Addition works properly, but the subtraction is going into negative. I tried different possible logic but could not find the appropriate. Where first two inputs along with minus button gives proper solution .This solution when used with third input for subtraction does not happen the way it should .There are 0-9 buttons to input digits. One **plus** button to trigger the below method
    `-(IBAction)adding:(id)sender;`
and one **minus** button to trigger this.
    `-(IBAction)subtract:(id)sender;`
an equals button for triggering 
`-(IBAction)equals:(id)sender;`
main functionality is to be added in the subtract and the main equals method 
Below is the code of the function implementations, i.e **.m** file.

```
int eq;

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize temp = _temp;
@synthesize inputField = _inputField;
@synthesize outputField = _outputField;

-(IBAction)adding:(id)sender
{
  self.temp = self.input + self.output;
  self.input = 0;
  eq = 0;

}

-(IBAction)subtract:(id)sender
{
  self.temp = self.input - self.output;
  self.input = 0;
  eq = 1;
}

-(IBAction)digits:(id)sender
{
  UIButton *b = (UIButton *)sender;
  self.input = self.input * 10 + b.tag;
  [self showInput];
}

-(IBAction)clear:(id)sender
{
  self.input = 0;
  [self showInput];
  self.output = 0;
  [self showOutput];
}

-(IBAction)clearE:(id)sender
{
  self.input = self.input * 0.1;
  [self showInput];
}

-(IBAction)equals:(id)sender
{
  if (eq == 0) {
    self.output = self.temp + self.input;
    self.temp = 3;
  }
  if (eq ==1)
  {
    self.output = self.temp - self.input;
    self.temp = 3;
  }
  [self showOutput];
  self.input = 0;
  [self showInput];
}

-(void)showInput
{
  self.inputField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lld", self.input];
}

-(void)showOutput
{
  self.outputField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lld", self.output];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  self.inputField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lld",self.input];
  self.outputField.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lld", self.output];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
  [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
  // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

The **.h** file is this :

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic,readwrite,weak) IBOutlet UILabel *inputField;
@property (assign,readwrite,) unsigned long long input;
@property(assign,readwrite) unsigned long long temp;
@property (nonatomic,readwrite,weak) IBOutlet UILabel *outputField;
@property (assign,readwrite) unsigned long long output;

-(IBAction)digits:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)adding:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)subtract:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)clear:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)clearE:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)equals:(id)sender;
@end
```

Comment: Shouldn't you subtract the input (the value just entered) from the output (the result of the last calculation)?

Comment: @Farhan I would suggest you watch the CS193p videos on making a calculator for iOS development. This is on iTunesU. Your code is very confusing. I think this video will help a lot.

Comment: Thanks @jamie started watching CS 193p right away. Thanks a lot for the heads up .